# adjacency list with multiple parent for some leaf?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a blog and in this blog we can have n-level category and I realy need to store a single post in several category. So i want adjancy list model with multiple parent for leaf nodes.
As i think we should create 3 table for creating many to many join, and my table are

Categories-tbl

```
Id    cat-name    Parent-id
```

Leaf-Posts-tbl

```
Id    post-name
```

Post-cat-tbl

```
post-id    cat-id
```

Now

I want all query we get from a simple adjacency list from this tables?

1.how can we get all leaf of parent?

2.get subtree childs

3.delete,update,insert...

Comment: Sounds like you know what you want... what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Orangepill in usual hierarchical data stored in one table , I want discuss about many to many relation. how traverse form leaf to root, or root to leaf and traverse subtress.